# Facebook user redirected to homepage after invalid login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a situation where I am using custom login for Facebook in my android app.

My workflow is :
1. I am using PHP redirection for authentication in webView. (Weird, I know but please bear with me).

```
header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?fields=id,name,email,gender&client_id=".APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".REDIRECT_URL."&scope=".SCOPES);
```

2. After the user has authenticated, he is redirected to Redirect URL provided by me. All good, all well.

Trouble is when there is some error during user login (Wrong password or network issue), in second attempt of logging, user is not sent to my URL, instead he is shown his FB homepage. Maybe the redirect URL is getting removed after the failure.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: I suppose the problem may be in the code surrounding the line of code you've provided. Can you post more of the relevant code?

Comment: It could be the redirection_url you provide. Can you provide some way to reproduce the error?